# Learning French by reading

Tags: vocabulaire

What are some of the books you can name that a beginner learner of French can read if he can read Le Petit Prince with occasionally peeping into a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can be easy to read books in French that you already know in English - the first few Harry Potters, for example. It can be tough going, but you already know the storyline, and a lot of words you don't know will become obvious from the context and your prior knowledge, cutting down on the story-breaking dictionary checks.

Comment: Sure. I do something similar to this: read programming manuals or texts on other subjects I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read some newspapers or magazines. That's what I do to learn english :).